# Fill devepxress DXTreeList with data 

Tags: c#, wpf, tree, devexpress

I have product table and category table.

My Categories have many sub categories.

products are connected to categories how i can show product data with category?

for example:

```
Cigarettes
  > Marlboro
     > Marlboro Light 5$
     > Marlboro Red 4.3$
```

For example `Marlboros` Category ID is 5

`Marlboro Light` and `Marlboro Red` are in Product table where CategoryID = 5

Please help me how i can display my data correctly

this is my category class

```
public class TreeData {
    internal int ID { private set; get; }
    internal string Header { private set; get; }
    internal int ParentID { private set; get; }
    internal TreeData(int id, string header, int parentId) {
        ID = id;
        Header = header;
        ParentID = parentId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind your [TreeListView](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridTreeListViewtopic) via the `TreeListView.KeyFieldName` and the `TreeListView.ParentFieldName` properties:

```
<dxt:TreeListControl Name="treeList">
    <dxt:TreeListControl.Columns>
    <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="Header"/>
    </dxt:TreeListControl.Columns>
    <dxt:TreeListControl.View>
        <dxt:TreeListView Name="treeListView1" AutoWidth="True"
            KeyFieldName="ID" ParentFieldName="ParentID"/>
    </dxt:TreeListControl.View>
</dxt:TreeListControl>
```

Related documentation article:[Binding to Self-Referential Data Structure](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9571)

Please also review the following tutorials:

- [Lesson 1 - Binding to Data](http://help.devexpress.com/WPF/CustomDocument9933.aspx)
- [Lesson 2 - Building a Tree in Unbound Mode](http://help.devexpress.com/WPF/CustomDocument9936.aspx)